# Deploy Spring MVC 3 Rest on WebSphere Application Server 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, websphere

I am trying to deploy a Spring 3 MVC Rest Application on WebSphere Application Server 8.0 and have not had any success.

Here is my controller class

`

```
@Controller
public class BookingService {

    public BookingService() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/xml")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        return "<test>test</test>";
    }
}
```

`

web.xml - servlet spec 3

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`

dispatcher-servlet.xml

`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven /> -->

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" /> 

<bean id="viewResolver" class=
"org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <entry key="json" value="application/xml" />
                </map>
            </property>
            <property name="viewResolvers">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                        <property name="viewClass"
                            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="defaultViews">
                <list>
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                        <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

`

I confirm that it does work on tomcat. In the tomcat logs the mapping is being created.

`INFO: Mapped "{[/test],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/xml],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.westjet.ens.services.BookingService.test()`

Doing a curl on http://localhost:8080/ens-das-web/api/test returns HTTP 200.

However in the was logs this does not appear and doing a curl http://localhost:9080/my-service-web/api/test returns 404 and the following response.

`
    
       
          
          
       
       Error 404: SRVE0295E: Error reported: 404

`

Also the WAS Log shows the following when doing a curl.

`[9/23/15 15:53:21:390 MDT] 00000089 PageNotFound  W org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ens-das-web/api/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'`

WAS logs:

`[9/23/15 15:20:52:809 MDT] 00000049 WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for application key default_host/ens-das-web
[9/23/15 15:20:58:993 MDT] 00000049 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [ens-das-web-0_1_war#ens-das-web-0.1.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
[9/23/15 15:20:59:176 MDT] 00000049 webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [ens-das-web-0_1_war#ens-das-web-0.1.war]:.Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
[9/23/15 15:20:59:178 MDT] 00000049 DispatcherSer I org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
[9/23/15 15:20:59:229 MDT] 00000049 XmlWebApplica I org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 23 15:20:59 MDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
[9/23/15 15:20:59:313 MDT] 00000049 XmlBeanDefini I org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
[9/23/15 15:20:59:749 MDT] 00000049 AutowiredAnno I org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init> JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[9/23/15 15:20:59:770 MDT] 00000049 DefaultListab I org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3c2306c: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,viewResolver,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
[9/23/15 15:21:00:615 MDT] 00000049 DispatcherSer I org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1436 ms
[9/23/15 15:21:00:615 MDT] 00000049 servlet       I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [ens-das-web-0_1_war] [/ens-das-web] [dispatcher]: Initialization successful.
[9/23/15 15:21:00:616 MDT] 00000049 webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module ENS Data Access Service has been bound to default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:5060,*:5061,*:443].`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: WebSphere - awful.  Can only assume it's some obscure configuration or deployment problem that prevents your app from working.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately production is WAS.

Comment: Hum, that's weird. I have tried your setup on my WAS 8.0 and everything works correctly, Is controller BookingService in package "com.example"?

Comment: Yeah its in the same package. The Rest Service works in Tomcat. Just the @RequestMapping endpoints are not working in WAS.

Comment: It appears my issue was that I was deploying a WAR file. Once I packaged the WAR file into an EAR it worked. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. For some reason maven was not cleaning the WEB-INF/classes folder and my @Controller class was not available.